# Dijkstra function for navigation for disadvantaged

Tags: algorithms

Is there a way we can write a function for Dijkstra to determine which node to enqueue and which to discard. This is for a navigation solution for people with disabilities where path to stairs may be shorter but not preferable to wheelchair bound individuals. The navigation solution should also support all individuals and only give a path discarding stairs if the specified user group is someone who is wheelchair bound etc. So basically i am attempting to write a function that checks if user group = wheelchair bound then removes the shortest path to stairs and gives the path to the nearest elevator.
I am pretty new to this so any assistance would be very much appreciated. My apologies for being unclear previously.

Comment: What do you mean? Wouldn't you just have to remove the edges corresponding to stairs from the graph?

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's algorithm already solves your problem. If a staircase is unusable for the wheelchair-bound, then the corresponding edge should not appear in the graph. If some other route is usable but very slow, then it should be weighted accordingly.

The same kind of problem is already encountered with cars – some paths are too narrow for them. A smart GIS takes this into account, removing the corresponding edges when you navigate your car, and keeping them when you navigate your walk.

The difficult aspect here is obtaining this information – which path is suitable for the wheelchair-bound, and which ones should get penalties. Whether it can be done automatically (with a few mistakes) depends on your situation, which you haven't described in enough detail.